# Appending All Entries in array to string?

Tags: arrays, ocaml, string-concatenation

I currently have an array containing x amount of strings and am looking to append all of these entries to a string in OCaml.

I know that the way to append a string to another in OCaml is by using

```
let a ="Hello"
let b= "Blah Blah " ^ a
```

However I would like to do this using all entries in my array. Then continue the string after appending the full array. Something similar to this:

```
let myArray = Array.make stages "Some text"
let myString = "I'm looking to append "^(ALL ENTRIES IN ARRAY)^" to this string"
```

Comment: Are you sure you should be using an array? That's not very idiomatic. In any case, your problem boils down to first concatenating the strings in the array, and then adding the prefix and suffix which you already know how to do. If you had used a list instead of an array you could have just used `String.concat`. With an array you can either use `Array.fold_left` with the concatenation operator, or just do it imperatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a list of strings rather than array then String.concat will do the trick. So if you have array you could convert the array to list and then apply String.concat as in:

```
String.concat " " (Array.to_list str_arr)
```

But if you don't want to convert it to a list you could use fold_left as in:

```
 Array.fold_left (fun x y -> x ^ y ^ " ") "" str_arr
```

Notice that fold_left appends a space to every string in the array including the last one. String.concat is better; it uses the filler only between the strings

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency's sake you may wish to use the [`Buffer`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Buffer.html) module for this.

> Extensible buffers.
>
> This module implements buffers that automatically expand as necessary.
> It provides accumulative concatenation of strings in linear time
> (instead of quadratic time when strings are concatenated pairwise).

```
# let s_arr = [|"foo"; "bar"; "baz"; "wooble"|] in
  let b = Buffer.create @@ Array.length s_arr * 4 in 
  Array.iter 
    (fun s -> Buffer.add_string b s; 
              Buffer.add_char b ' ') 
    s_arr;
  Buffer.contents b;; 
- : string = "foo bar baz wooble "
```